# How cautiously should std::shared_ptr be handled?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I was somewhat surprised to find that `std::shared_ptr` provides no protection (eg, throw an exception) against situations when its pointed-to object has somehow been deleted. I imagine this is for performance reasons; assuming `shared_ptr` is doing its job the object the `shared_ptr` points to should have never been deleted, so it'd be silly to waste the cycles constantly checking.

I know I can check explicitly for whether a `shared_ptr` is valid, but if `shared_ptr` is "doing its job" to maintain object lifetime it would seem overkill to explicitly check every time I touch a `shared_ptr`.

So my question is, how cautious should I be in light of this? Is there a "rule of thumb" as to if, how often, or when I should check the `shared_ptr`?

My best conclusion so far would mimic Java: Any time you're handed a reference to an object in Java that you didn't create, you should check it for `null`. Would this be a good policy for `shared_ptr`?

Comment: `shared_ptr<int> ptr;` creates a null pointer. Why do you think this should throw? `shared_ptr` will throw if you try to dereference a null pointer, but having a null pointer is not exceptional at all. It's not like `shared_ptr` can get set to null behind your back. Pointers are only set to null when you set them to null, one way or another.

Comment: @bames53: `shared_ptr will throw if you try to dereference a null pointer` since when? In fact, the dereference operator is marked `noexcept`. Anyway, Bret is talking about pointers that originate in another scope, e.g. passed into one of his functions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right, it doesn't. I'm thinking of a different smart pointer class used in projects I work on. So strike out "`shared_ptr` will throw if you try to dereference a null pointer, but" and just leave "having a null pointer is not exceptional at all".

Comment: "*situations when its pointed-to object has somehow become null*" How on earth could this ever happen unless you're already in UB-land? This seems like a total non-question to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like any other pointer, check it before you use it if you have any reason to suspect that it might wrap a null pointer.

`shared_ptr` does help to manage the lifetime of an object that it points to, but that is a completely separate task from deciding whether it *does* point to an object.

Comment: Thanks, after reading my question again, I realized I was misleading with my use of the word `null` (Java habit, I guess), yet you still managed to give me a pretty sensible answer.

Answer (score 4):

> *`std::shared_ptr` provides no protection (eg, throw an exception) against situations when its pointed-to object has somehow become
>   null.*

The C++ language recognizes no such thing as a NULL object.

If you mean protection against an object getting **deleted**, you can absolutely protect against that, by not mixing smart pointers and raw pointers to the same object.

If you only have smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` pointing to an object, you never have to delete the object and it won't get deleted prematurely.

Comment: He clearly means `when the pointer that sometimes points to a pointed-to object has somehow become null`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The pointer stored in a `shared_ptr`?  Isn't it well-defined when that becomes NULL?  Or at least well-defined when it won't?  If that's what you mean, I think my answer addresses that.

Comment: Not really. A "null pointer" is well defined: it's a pointer with the value `0`. De-allocation of objects has nothing to do with it, which is what your answer seems to be talking about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A null pointer is well defined, I agree.  I didn't intend to imply that it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

As a practice I don't use null pointers (or null smart pointers) to convey state because it complicates whether and when you should be checking for null and complication == bugs. Therefore I *never* check for null, I just use the pointer knowing it's good.

The only time I use null pointers is for deferred initialization of members (sometimes a pointer will get constructed after some reading of some data so I can't initialize it in the member initialization list).

Comment: You don't "know" that it's good. You may have forgotten to initialise it, or you may accidentally have name hiding giving you a `shared_ptr` that perhaps isn't the one you thought it was. Though that's the stuff of `assert`, I guess

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I guess. I assert for cases like that. I don't try to error handle internal code bugs that should never happen, I only handle errors caused from external sources.

Comment: Ah, `assert` makes a lot of sense. I recently saw some asinine code that checked 7-8 pointers for `null` in a series of nested `if` statements. The code started to approach a dozen levels of indentation and it hadn't yet done anything of substance. With that in mind, I was wondering if such an ugly practice could be automatically avoided with a `shared_ptr`. It seems, instead, whether a raw pointer or `smart_ptr`, one should simply `assert` and let the code "bomb out" if an external source caused undefined behavior.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that my original question wasn't implying the use of `null` to indicate state. I'm, as you, very much against that practice.